# sqoop Redirecting the output of expect to logfile in expect

Tags: shell, unix, sqoop2

how we can redirect all sqoop command stdout and stderror to log file .so that when i run sqoop command it should not show any message in screen .

I am using below but still showing messga e

`sqoop command 2>.&1 >>logfile`

Answer (score 1):

Redirect stdout/stderr to a file

```
sqoop import command &> logfiile.log
```